# Extension is not recognized after a bridge from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, class-extensions, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have question for expert on Swift and Objective-C.
I'm developing on iOS project in swift.
In this project, I have import an older owned library (in Objective-C) used with a Objective-C bridge.

When I use some function of this library in my Swift project, I encountered a crash due to unrecognized extension.

The error message is:

> -[NSConcreteMutableData AES128EncryptedDataWithKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

This method come from an extension class in my library (NSData+AES128.h) which is not recognized in Swift side.
Someone knows how refer this extension in Swift side? I'm really lost!!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a runtime error, not a compiler/Swift error. So very likely You forgot to add the .m file to your project that implements this category/extension, but the header must obviously be there, as otherwise you'd get compiler warnings about it.

Comment: No, It's not the reason. The library has not warning, and it works fine with Objective-C Project.
But with Swift project I have this error, as if the bridge do not take into account this extension.

Comment: Is the target membership on the .m file in the Swift target checked? Do you have any build settings that eliminate unused code in the ObjC target but not in Swift?